# The set of all limit points $A'$ of a subset of a topological space $X$ is empty if $\tau = 2^X$

Tags: general-topology

> **Proposition**: If $X$ is a topological space with $\tau = 2^X$, then $A' = \emptyset$ where $A \subset X$

I found the proof and it uses the fact that if $x \in A$, then $\{ x\} \cap A - \{x \} = \emptyset$ since $\{x\}$ is open.

But it does not address what happens if $X = \{x,y,z \}$ and say $A = \{x,y \}$.

So if i take $A$ to be a neighbourhood of $x$, then  $A \cap A - \{x \} = \{ y\} \neq \emptyset.$ The claim is wrong.

I am guessing I misunderstood the claim? What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: What does it mean saying $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$?

Comment: It means if every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in some other point than $\{ x \}$. I took $A$ to be a neighbourhood of $x$ itself since $A$ is open.

Comment: So if you wan't to show $x$ is *not* a limit point of $A$, you only need to find *one* neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ such that $A\cap O-\{x\}=\varnothing$. And I think you did that.

Comment: But how does showing *one* neighbourhood intersecting in an empty fashion show the claim when there are neighbourhoods that don't intersect in an nonempty fashion

Comment: May I ask what it means to say "$x$ is *not* a limit point of $A$?"

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean now. My example was red herring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose x be a limit point of a subset A of X.That would mean if you take any open set U of X containing x then intersection of A with U-{x} is non-empty.But as X is given with discrete topology.So {x} is itself an open set of X.Take U={x},then intersection of A with U-{x} is empty.That imply x is not a limit point of A.
As x is arbitrary that imply A has no limit point.So $A'=\emptyset$.